# How do i put a variable in file.open()

Tags: c++, arrays, string, variables, loops

I am trying to put a variable file name in a file.open() function, but i keep getting this error:

> [Error] no matching function for call to `'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)'`

The code:

```
for (int x=1; x<=num_pages; x++){
    file= page_name[x];
    cout << file;
ofstream file;
file.open ("file");
...
file.close();
}
```

What I am working on is a program that able to ask for multiple file name as write those file according to the text I assign. I guess I should point out that all the file names are put into an array and looped out.
*Also how can I put a file extension at the end.
This is the error i got...
[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream::open(std::string&)'

Comment: When you say "getting an error", it's important that you also **tell us what the error is** so we don't have to guess. You have that information right in front of you (if you didn't, you wouldn't know you got an error), so you should include it in your question. We can't see your screen from where we're sitting. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information there, where people reading it can see it. You should *never* put important information in comments.

Comment: @KenWhite I post it u have any idea wats wrong

Answer (score 5):

You can't have two variables with the same name. It looks like you're trying to name a string `file` as well as an `ofstream`. Try renaming the first variable (the string) to `filename`. Then you can do:

```
file.open(filename);
```